# Create 2 columns based on information on 1 column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Based on table_1:

```
cost_apple   cost_pear      cost_banana
€3              €2               €1
```

I would like to create table_2:

```
fruit      cost
apple       €3
banana      €2
pear        €1
```

How can I achieve that?

Edit:
table with date attached to it

```
date      cost_apple   cost_pear      cost_banana
2020-01-01 €3              €2               €1
```

Expected table:

```
date        fruit      cost
2020-01-01  apple       €3
2020-01-02  banana      €2
2020-01-02  pear        €1
2021-01-03  banana      €5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the "ugly" and manual way

```
create table table_2 as
select 'apple' as fruit, cost_apple as cost from table_1 union all
select 'banana' as fruit, cost_pear as cost from table_1 union all
select 'pear' as fruit, cost_banana as cost from table_1
```

Or the "nice" way (unpivot the data)

```
create table table_2 as
select t.* 
from table_1
  cross join lateral (
    values
      (table_1.cost_apple, 'apple'),
      (table_1.cost_pear, 'pear'),
      (table_1.cost_banana, 'banana')
  ) as t(fruit, cost)
```

The unpivot without dynamic sql is still another manual way to do the same

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you please provide a solution where I have date attached to the cost_apple, cost_pear, cost_banana? I tried to input the date into the cross join lateral ( values date,  'date',  table_1.cost_apple, 'apple'), ...) didnt work

Comment: try adding to the second query `select table_1.date, t.*`, instead of `select t.*`. If the answer is right please vote it as correct.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you're taking the good way.

1- You have a Fruits class with extends apple, banana and pear.

2- the fruit class contains a price column and if you absolutely need aénother table, create a price table with the amount(1, 2, 3, 4...) and the symbol (€, $.....)

Difficult to help you with these informations but keep in mind that a cost_apple or a cost_pear is a cost.... just need one column for this.